# SQL: Understanding GROUPING SET

Tags: group-by, union

As far as I can understand, the purpose of a `GROUPING SET` is to combine summary rows with raw data rows. This can also be achieved by combining a table with `GROUP BY` summaries with the `UNION` clause, but the `GROUPING SET` form is merely more efficient since it does the work in a single pass.

Is that a reasonable understanding of `GROUPING SET`?

Comment: I've cropped out the ROLLUP and CUBE part because @sp_BlitzErik is right to say it adds nothing to *this* question, except making the scope confusing. You're right to say though that they're just shorthands of `GROUPING SET`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> As far as I can understand, the purpose of a GROUPING SET is to combine summary rows with raw data rows.

Yes, but the [PostgreSQL docs on `GROUPING SETS`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/static/queries-table-expressions.html#queries-grouping-sets) are a little clearer,

> More complex grouping operations than those described above are possible using the concept of *grouping sets*. The data selected by the `FROM` and `WHERE` clauses is **grouped separately by each specified grouping set, aggregates computed for each group just as for simple GROUP BY clauses, and then the results returned.**

But it's not just more efficient. Marshaling different aggregates into a single result set requires them all to return NULL for the columns that the others are aggregating over. That's not easy to maintain nor create in large queries.

For instance,

```
CREATE TABLE foo(x,y)
AS VALUES
  (1,1),
  (2,2),
  (1,2);
```

With the query of,

```
SELECT x, y, count(*)
FROM foo
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS ((x),(y),())
ORDER BY x,y;

 x | y | count 
---+---+-------
 1 |   |     2
 2 |   |     1
   | 1 |     1
   | 2 |     2
   |   |     3
(5 rows)
```

Could be rewritten as

```
SELECT x, null AS y, count(*)    -- GROUPING SET (x)
FROM foo
GROUP BY x

UNION ALL

  SELECT null, y, count(*)       -- GROUPING SET (y)
  FROM foo 
  GROUP BY y

  UNION ALL

    SELECT null, null, count(*)  -- NULL GROUPING SET
    FROM foo;
```

But each level of that `UNION` will require knowledge of the aggregations written in the rest of the query.

*Syntax and examples tested with PostgreSQL*